# is there an easy way to shuffle a string into an array?

Tags: vb.net

I got some trouble to adapt myself to visual basic and I think my algorithm is wrong right now.

I have to create kind of a word shuffle game, at first I had to declare an array with few word in then select a random word in this same array for displayed it in a label. Until now I sucess to do what i wanted to.

But here's the problem, now I have to select this same word and shuffle it randomly into an other array in order to display it for the user. The problem is that I'm strugling with *first* the vocabulary of visual basic and *secondly* i think my way of doing it is wrong, cause it will cost a lot of ressources if my "null" condition is not filled quickly. But I don't know what to do apart of this method.

Of course it doesn't work either in this state, I'm not sure why but at best i get a single char...

So this is my code so far :

```cpp
Public Sub shuffle(ByVal chain As String)
        '''METHOD'''
        '''Shuffle the letter randomly'''
        Dim arrayShuffled(theWord.Length) As String
        Dim pointer As Integer = 0
        Dim pointerRand As Integer

        //I want to loop around theWord Array
        For i As Integer = 0 To theWord.Length - 1

            //Try to give a random position arrayShuffle
            pointerRand = (rand.Next(0, arrayShuffled.Length))

            //Loop till you find a null index 
            Do Until arrayShuffled(pointerRand) = ""
                pointerRand = (rand.Next(0, arrayShuffled.Length))
            Loop

            //Then give to this index the char from theWord where index = pointeur
            arrayShuffled(pointerRand) = theWord(pointer)
            pointeur += 1

        Next

        //Here this : (rand.Next(0, ArrayShuffled.Length - 1)) feel wrong but I don't know if we can bypass the condition from the declaration with () in other word I don't really know what to put in the ()
        lblWord.Text = ArrayShuffled(rand.Next(0, ArrayShuffled.Length - 1)) 
    End Sub
```

I wish I was clear enough, thanks for your help.

PS: Shame on me but I'm not sure wish VB I'm using right now, I think it's the VB6 but visual studio don't give me the answer

Comment: That's not vb6, it would be vb.net.

Comment: Thanks ! I edited it

Comment: `lblWord.Text = String.Join("", chain.OrderBy(Function(x) rand.NextDouble()))`

Comment: Thank you so much it works, i was so far and i think i would never have found this answer....

Comment: A slight variation of dr.null's answer: `lblWord.Text = New String(chain.OrderBy(Function(x) rand.NextDouble()).ToArray)`

Comment: Look up Fisher-Yates shuffle, that's the canonical way to shuffle a fixed-length collection.